# Hard Corrupted Outlook PST File

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

I have a problem with PST file which is corrupted after I moved it to different location. I move 4 PST files - 1 was OK, 1 fixed with SCANPST.EXE and 2 cant be fixed with anything. Both have around 800MB. I tried nearly each avaible program to fix this, but none worked.
All programs I tried cant even show me whats inside or whats structure of mailbox.

Is there uncongenial way how to get any emails atleast?

Comment: This is one of those occasions where you should have checked your data before deleting the original; or keep a proper backup structure. Outside chance, it's still on the IMAP server. Probably out of luck if it's POP3.

Comment: True, I did this like 30 times before and this is first time this happened. I doubt we can find this specific file elsewhere than this computer.

Comment: What error is displayed after running the scanpst tool? Based on the official document, multiple passes are sometimes required to fix all errors. As a suggestion, maybe you could try to do multiple scans to check :  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/data-files/inbox-repair-tool-scanpst-exe-run-multiple-passes